# Ubuntu 20.04 will not resume from suspend on HP Laptop: Why?

Tags: laptop, hp, 20.04, resume

I have a HP EliteBook-8540p running a Core™ i7 CPU Q 720 processor with 12GB of RAM.
It has been running Ubuntu since I purchased it in March 2016.
I have upgraded versions as newer versions became available, and it has never missed a beat, until Focal Fossa, 20.04.

After suspending Ubuntu, pressing the power button to resume brings the laptop back to life, but there is no screen display, and it appears that there is no disk activity.

This is from the syslog, where I have attempted to resume, but eventually had to power reset.
There is nothing recorded that shows I attempted the resume.

```
May 17 13:13:45 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1589685225.8086] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May 17 13:13:45 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1589685225.8088] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May 17 13:13:45 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p whoopsie[1637]: [13:13:45] offline
May 17 13:13:51 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
May 17 13:13:51 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 17 13:13:51 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p wpa_supplicant[1198]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
May 17 13:13:51 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p kernel: [ 6938.098208] PM: suspend entry (deep)
May 17 13:13:51 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd-sleep[5415]: Suspending system...
May 17 14:01:46 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
May 17 14:01:46 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
May 17 14:01:46 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd[1]: Finished udev Coldplug all Devices.
May 17 14:01:46 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd-modules-load[403]: Inserted module 'lp'
May 17 14:01:46 kevin-HP-EliteBook-8540p systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
```

I found an HDD with the 16.04 installation, which I cloned, and installed.
It ran correctly, and resumed from suspend.
I ran the software updater, and then the 16.04 had the same problem, it would not resume from a suspend, and exhibited the same fault of the 20.04 installation.
I am now running of another 16.04 clone, with updates disabled.

`syslog` from functioning 16.04 installation.

```
May 25 10:47:05 me-hp-elitebook-8540p systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 25 10:47:05 me-hp-elitebook-8540p systemd-sleep[8394]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
May 25 10:47:05 me-hp-elitebook-8540p systemd-sleep[8396]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
May 25 10:47:05 me-hp-elitebook-8540p systemd-sleep[8394]: Suspending system...
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.516243] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.974414] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.974758] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.977015] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.978258] PM: Suspending system (mem)
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.978333] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.978842] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
May 25 16:29:54 me-hp-elitebook-8540p kernel: [ 6460.978954] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
```